# docker-compose named volume with one file: ERROR: Cannot create container for service, source is not directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf, docker-volume

I am trying to make the binary file `/bin/wkhtmltopdf` from the container `wkhtmltopdf` available in the `web` container. I try to achieve this with a named volume.

I have the following docker container setup in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
    web:
        image: php:7.4-apache
        command: sh -c "mkdir -p /usr/local/bin && touch /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
        entrypoint: sh -c "exec 'apache2-foreground'"
        volumes:
            - wkhtmltopdfvol:/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
            
    wkhtmltopdf:
        image: madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf
        command: sh -c "touch /bin/wkhtmltopdf"
        entrypoint: sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"  # workaround to keep container running
        volumes: 
            - wkhtmltopdfvol:/bin/wkhtmltopdf

volumes:
    wkhtmltopdfvol:
```

However, I get the following error when running `docker-compose up`:

```
ERROR: for wkhtmltopdf  Cannot create container for service wkhtmltopdf:
source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/42e7082b8024ae4ebb13a4f0003a9e17bc18b33ef0677431dd002da3c21dde88/merged/bin/wkhtmltopdf is not directory
```

> .../bin/wkhtmltopdf is not directory

Does that mean that I can't share **one file** between containers but only directories through a named volume? How do I achieve this?

**Edit**: I also noticed that `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` inside the `web` container **is a directory and not a file** as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tricky to share binaries between containers like this.  Volumes probably aren't the mechanism you're looking for.

If you look at the [Docker Hub page for the `php` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) you can see that `php:7.4-apache` is an alias for (currently) `php:7.4.15-apache-buster`, where "Buster" is the name of a Debian release.  You can then search on https://packages.debian.org/ to discover that Debian has a prepackaged [wkhtmltopdf](https://packages.debian.org/buster/wkhtmltopdf) package.  You can install this using a custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      wkhtmltopdf
# COPY ...
# Base image provides EXPOSE, CMD
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file needs to build this image:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    # no image:, volumes:, or command: override
```

Just in terms of the mechanics of sharing binaries like this, you can run into trouble where a binary needs a shared library that's not present in the target container.  The `apt-get install` mechanism handles this for you.  There are also potential troubles if a container has a different shared-library ecosystem (especially Alpine-based containers), or using host binaries from a different operating system.

---

The Compose file you show mixes several concepts in a way that doesn't really work.  A named volume is always a directory, so trying to mount that over the `/bin/wkhtmltopdf` file in the second container causes the error you see.  There's a dependency issue for which container starts up first and gets to create the volume.  A container only runs a single command, and if you have both `entrypoint:` and `command:` then the command gets passed as extra arguments to the entrypoint (and if the entrypoint is an `sh -c ...` invocation, effectively ignored).

If you really wanted to try this approach, you should make `web: {depends_on: [wkhtmltopdf]}` to force the dependency order.  The second container should mount the volume somewhere else, it probably shouldn't have an `entrypoint:`, and it should do something like `command: cp -a /bin/wkhtmltopdf /export`.  (It will exit immediately once this `cp` finishes, but that shouldn't matter.)  The first container can then mount the volume on, say, `/usr/local/bin`, and not specially set `command:` or `entrypoint:`.  There will still be a minor race condition (you're not guaranteed the `cp` command will complete before Apache starts) but it probably wouldn't be a practical problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You are right, it isn't really clever to share binaries like this because of it's dependencies... I couldn't find any official documentation saying that named volumes only allow directories though... Do you have a link for that?